# How do you purge a removed app? or delete snapshot after app removal

Tags: snap

I removed an app with snap:

```
sudo snap remove app-name
```

Then I realised I should have added `--purge` argument to disable snapshot. When I tried to

```
sudo snap remove app-name --purge
```

it says the app-name does not exist, which is fair.

The question is now how do I remove the saved files or the created snapshot?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As I was writing the question, I quickly realized I could use the `snapshot` commands:

```
$ snap help

...
Snapshots: saved, save, check-snapshot, restore, forget
...
```

Looks like I need to find the saved snapshots with `saved` and then `forget` it.

```
$ sudo snap saved

Set  Snap      Age    Version  Rev  Size    Notes
1    app-name  4m30s  1.2.0    25   1.89MB  auto

$ sudo snap forget 1
```

Works.

Hope this obvious answer could help others.