# will docker volumes remain if I do snap remove?

Tags: snap, docker

I have docker installed via `snap`. I would like to install it via `apt` instead (long story).

One of my docker services is a very big database. It is using a volume.

I figured I should do `snap remove docker` and then install docker via `apt`, but I am a little confused about whether the volumes will be removed or not. I don't want the volume to be deleted.

From my understanding, `snap remove docker` will create a "snapshot" (backup) of docker. But will it remove `/var/lib/docker/volumes`?

For instance, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374550/how-to-restore-docker-containers-after-snap-remove-docker) mentions that **containers** are removed with `snap remove docker`, which would lead me to believe that the answer is yes: volumes are removed.

EDIT: I just testet (something somewhat relevant) on a different server. I did `snap remove --purge docker` and it removed the folder `/var/snap/docker` where some volumes were residing. Unfortunately this doesn't really confirm whether `snap remove docker` would remove `/var/lib/docker/volumes`  or not. I am leaning towards yes.

I am not going to use `snap` for docker anymore, that's for sure :)

Comment: The `--purge` option told it to "*Remove the snap without saving a snapshot of its data*" ie. it removed snapshots of data as you directed it to (ie. --purge tells it to not save data; the quoted text from `man snap` for my release)

Comment: Doing `snap remove docker` without the `--purge` flag seems to take an eternity. Probably because it creates a backup of the entire db server with all data (not just a regular db data dump).

Comment: I'm generally using [*bind mounts*](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) instead of volumes for persistent data, since I can then better control where the data is located and backed up.

Comment: Bind mounts are slower than volumes. It had a huge impact on the performance of our queries. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65876200/2583765

Comment: I guess that depends on the usecase - I don't have much experience with Docker volumes, but the [documentation states](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) that: "Volumes are easier to back up or migrate than bind mounts". So I would imagine there is an easy way to back up and restore volumes.

Comment: That's probably true. But it will take a long time to back up and restore the volume. It would be much better if snap could just leave the /var/lib/docker/volumes folder alone when uninstalling docker.

Comment: I am with you about not using docker with snap. Another reason why not to do it is that snap does not work on containers not running with the correct configurations because. More on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70017209/is-there-a-minimum-system-specification-for-installing-snap/74263252#74263252